# Can a SQL command from database be used in a SSIS variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I know that it's possible to use in a SSIS package a SQL command which is scripted in the expression of a variable.

But is it possible to define the SQL command in a database table, get it from the database, put it in a SSIS variable and then use it in an OLE DB source?

I made a try - similar to the version in which the command is scripted in the variable expression.

But this don't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible (though I never like the  idea of storing SQL commands in a table and arbitrarily running them; that's a great avenue for SQL injection like attacks). Why didn't your attempt work?

Comment: Instead of variable expression, try `Execute SQL Task`.  You can set this to a single row result and populate a variable with the resultset.  That can subsequently be used in an OLEDB source as @billinkc noted in his answer (SQL Command from Variable)

Answer (score 1):

An OLE DB Source has 4 choices for input

- table or view
- table or view name from variable
- SQL Command
- SQL Command from variable

How the value of the variable is populated (hard coded, uses expressions, populated via Execute SQL Task, package parameter, Script Task) does not matter. The data type however, does matter. I think you're limited to 4000 characters for your String Variables in SSIS. If you've defined a table in SQL Server as n/varchar(max) then you'll see an issue at the Execute SQL Task shoving something too big into a into the box.

What can't happen with the query is that it cannot change shape.

Original query in table

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM myTable WHERE col3 > 100;
```

Updated query, works fine

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM myTable WHERE col3 > 200;
```

Updated query, package fails validation

```
SELECT col1, col2, col4 FROM myTable WHERE col3 > 100;
```

You can also run into difficulties with metadata if the source of your data is  a stored procedure as the first query in the procedure, even if it does not return rows, is used to set the metadata. This behaviour has changed over time so pre 2012? you cheated by having a no-op query in there like (or maybe the query is also commented out, it's been a decade since I've dealt with it)

```
SELECT 1 AS col1, 2 AS col2 FROM sys.databases AS D WHERE NULL = NULL;
```

The package will identify that we have two integer columns named col1, col2 and then the actual query happens N lines down. SQL Server 2012+ you can simply use the `WITH RESULTS SET` option to describe the intended metadata.